# Query returns all items in the database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The following code:

```
$orders = Order::with([
  "logs"
])
->where("is_succcessfully_created", true)
->orWhere("order_no", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("traveler_first_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("traveler_last_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("contact_person_first_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("contact_person_last_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("contact_person_email", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("contact_person_primary_phone", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("contact_person_alternate_phone", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("return_person_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->orWhere("return_person_phone", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
->get();
```

It returns all the entries from the database. Is there anything wrong with my Eloquent statement? Could it be because of where `->where("is_succcessfully_created", true)` statement?

Comment: Try replacing `->get()` with `->toSql()` to take a look at the generated query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data `is_succcessfully_created = true` and `(("order_no", "like", "%{$req->search}%") or ("traveler_first_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%") ...)`, you can be written as below:

```
$orders = Order::with([
            "logs"
        ])->where("is_succcessfully_created", true)
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where("order_no", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("traveler_first_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("traveler_last_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("contact_person_first_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("contact_person_last_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("contact_person_email", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("contact_person_primary_phone", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("contact_person_alternate_phone", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("return_person_name", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
                    ->orWhere("return_person_phone", "like", "%{$req->search}%")
            })->get();
```

Comment: Right now it only searches for "order_no" column. I have `traveler_first_name` as `Aris`, but it cannot find it when I search for `Ari`. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `is_succcessfully_created` is `false`.

Comment: It is not. Something seems strange.

Comment: Could you share your database with me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there could be a problem due to `orWhere` statements.

In your case, if there is no `succcessfully_created` order then the query will search one record which meets one of the rest `orWhere` statements.

Therefore you are getting **all or almost all** of the orders.

You should put the all orWhere statements into the nested where function:

```
->where("is_succcessfully_created", true)
->orWhere(function($query) {
     ...
     all current orWhere go here 
     ...
})
```